# How to update the content of a nodejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Suppose I have a file `abc.ts` having the following content

```
... // some other content

switch(item) {
case 1: break;
case 2: break;
.
.
. 
case x: break;
default: break;
}

...

export const someOtherUnrelatedVariable = 'Help me out';

...
```

Now I have another file `change.ts` that needs to add more case statements in the switch case clause in `abc.ts` programmatically.

I want to achieve it using NodeJS only. Can I do it?

Comment: I don't think this is something that should be done the way you have outlined. It should be done using data structures like array and adding to the array and using this array to populate the switch case using for loop. If persistent storage is required, it should be stored in a JSON file and then this file should be used for generating the switch case. You should NEVER write to a `.js` file.

Comment: Hi VPaul, the example that  I gave is not exactly what I want to do. In general terms, I want to update the content of one ts file from another ts file. There are a bunch of functionality that is repeated way too often in my code and I am trying to automate it. It could be adding a new object in my file and export it or insert a whole new function in another file, programatically.

Comment: [You're kidding, aren't you?](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2020/04/16/a-story-of-duplicate-code/)

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do it?

Yes, there are ways to do this.

But you're asking the wrong question. Should you do it? **No!**

> In general terms, I want to update the content of one ts file from another ts file. There are a bunch of functionality that is repeated way too often in my code and I am trying to automate it.

Instead of automating code-writing, you should refactor your code to avoid duplication altogether. Use the proper data structures and code structures (such as loops) so that you do not have to repeat functionality.

Comment: Its not about code that can be optimized. An apt example would be, using redux and saga in a react project. For adding one state variable a user needs to update the state object, create an action, a reducer, a saga function which usually has the same boiler plate code with the new state variable name and interfaces changing. So you see, there is nothing to optimize out here but to find a way to generate boilerplate code automatically.

Comment: So you're saying it's not functionality that is duplicated, only boilerplate is? Then a stored snippet in your IDE should suffice

Comment: Exactly. Sorry for my bad choice of words. Now the thing is I thought about a stored snippet (or an extension for my VSCode IDE), but I was thinking in terms of building an NPM lib for it so that it can be installed globally and used irrespective of any IDE. Again, excuse me if my knowledge on snippet usages in IDE isn't clear.